# Where in on an index

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySql table:

```
id INT(10),
property_id INT(10),
value_id INT(10),
..
```

There's an index 'combination' on property_id + value_id

I have an array containing for example [1 => 68, 4 => 8, 9 => 15, ...]

Instead of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (property_id = 1 && value_id = 68) 
|| (property_id = 4 && value_id = 8) 
|| (property_id = 9 && value_id = 15) 
|| ...
```

i hoped something as this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE combination IN ('1_68', '4_8', '9_15', ...)
```

I now know this does not work. But is there another way i can accomplish this?

Comment: Just use your language of choice to build your query from that array

Comment: Mihai, the question is not how to create the array. The question is: is it possible to query an index instead of field of the table. And if so; how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use tuples for conditions:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (property_id, value_id) IN (
    (1, 68),
    (4, 8),
    (9, 15) 
);
```

This is how it should work. But yes - MySQL doesn't use the index properly. We can just hope it will do some day (AFAIK it works for PostgreSQL).

If it is about performance and you need it now, then you might consider to use an [indexed virtual (generated) column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns.html) (available in MySQL 5.7.8).

```sql
ALTER TABLE `locations`
ADD COLUMN `combination` VARCHAR(21) GENERATED ALWAYS AS CONCAT(property_id, '_', value_id),
ADD INDEX `combination` (`combination`);
```

And now you can use your query

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE combination IN ('1_68', '4_8', '9_15', ...)
```

If you want to save some memory you can combine two INTs into one BIGINT

```sql
ADD COLUMN `combination` VARCHAR(21) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((property_id << 32) + value_id)
```

You can also just use `UNION ALL`

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (property_id, value_id) = (1,68)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (property_id, value_id) = (4,8)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (property_id, value_id) = (9,15)
```

This will be fast. It's a shame that MySQL isn't doing that trivial optimisation.

Comment: In this case the index will not be used what makes the query very slow.

Comment: @PeterdeGroot, it's still like 40% faster than using concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat(property_id,'_',value_id) IN ('1_68', '4_8', '9_15', ...)
```

Comment: In this case the index will not be used what makes the query very slow.